# EF CTP5 OnModelCreating and MapSingleType

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We're starting a new project and are looking to use the Entity Framework.

I've been reading up on a lot of the new features in CTP 5 and especially like the new validation features, which I believe are only available if you use code first.

I read a blog post on Scott Gu's site about how to map the objects to table fields by using the Fluent API and the MapSingleType method. However it looks like this method was replaced in CTP5. Am I better off holding off on this as I don't really want to invest too much time for the CTP6 release to change the way this is done again?

Comment: I too am interested in whether it's wise to invest time on these CTP releases for Code First.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will *NOT* going be a CTP6. CTP5 is the *last* beta version for Code First before they release the RTM in the first quarter of 2011 which means what you see in CTP5 is pretty much what you'll get in the RTM. After all, if you still want to wait until the RTM become available, it's your call.

Comment: From ADO.NET team blog: `CTP5 will be our final preview of Code First and the simplified API surface (DbContext) before we offer a full supported production ready release in Q1 of 2011.` you can see it for yourself:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/12/06/ef-feature-ctp5-released.aspx